# How to check Android SDK version, Android Build Tools version and Android Support Repository version in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

how can i check what are my Android SDK version, Android Build Tools version and Android Support Repository version of a project in Android studio?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Configurations related to the `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersions` which are used in the project are in `build.gradle` of your app module. You can configure it to use any other version as per your requirements.

[image]

> Android Support Repository version of a project in Android studio?

Now support libraries have been changed to `androidx` and are a part of Jetpack. Previous support libraries included in the android studio are deprecated now. You can read about these [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/).